# Django reloading static files on every page

Tags: html, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-staticfiles

I'm looking at my elastic-beanstalk's HTTP request logs for my Django app and I can see that for every new page request (/login, /password_reset, etc.) the client's browser is requesting the whole static folder again and again (css, js, and fonts).

My understanding was that these files only load once until the user clears cache.

I have a `base.html` that extends to all pages:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    {% load staticfiles %}

    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script> -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/flat-ui-pro.js' %}"></script>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" />
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'css/flat-ui-pro.css' %}" />
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'css/custom_css.css' %}" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
```

Is there something I should be doing to prevent this?

Some more information that might be related:

in my `settings.py` file:

```
########  Depolyment Security #############
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'
```

Comment: How do you serve static files? If Django serves them (which is quite inefficient), then it's not surprising, as it doesn't send any cache-related headers. If you run `collectstatic` and have a webserver pointing to this directory, then it's something else... Django-related code you've posted is okay, but it doesn't have anything related to actually serving static files. Please check/show the deployment-related configuration.

Comment: My static files are being served by elastic-beanstalk itself which does it automatically at the time of deployment. In my deployment config file, I have the collectstatic command running at each deployment so I think that won't be an issue.